# Else loop doesn't seem to be triggering when meeting its' parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my intro to Python class we are required to make a simplistic program which utilizes the while loop. The program is supposed to take grades, then once the user is done inputting grades it will print the average, highest, and lowest grades. My professor also advised us to just have any negative number be the trigger for the end of inputs.

I've tried using various types of loops to get the program to stop taking inputs but it does not seem to stop when inputting a negative number.

```
grades = []

print('When done inputting grades input any negative number.')
grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))

while (grade >= 0):
    grades.append(grade)
else:
    avg_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    print('Average grade: ' , avg_grade)
    print('Lowest grade: ' , min(grades))
    print('Highest grade: ', max(grades))
```

So basically the only issue with this here is that I can't figure out how to get it to stop taking inputs, it seems to work when I put a . negative number as the first input but I cannot understand why it won't end the loop.

Comment: I believe you should have `grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))` inside your while loop otherwise you are only taking one value.

Comment: The loop needs to contain everything that happens repeatedly. You want to ask for input repeatedly, so that goes inside the loop. The problem isn't that your code won't "stop taking inputs"; quite the opposite - the problem is that it keeps *using* the one input that was given, instead of taking another one.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop never modifies `grade`, so the loop never ends. You need to ask for the input inside the loop.

Rather than duplicating the code that asks for input, just do it once, inside the loop. Use `break` to stop the loop when you get the terminating value.

There's no need to use `else:`. That's used when you have a loop that can either run to completion when the condition fails, or terminate early with `break`, and you want to do something special if it runs to completion. But your loop always ends on the same condition.

```
while True:
    grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))
    if grade == 0:
        break
avg_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
print('Average grade: ' , avg_grade)
print('Lowest grade: ' , min(grades))
print('Highest grade: ', max(grades))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a much simpler, and somehow more understandable way of explaining it than my professor did. I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is getting the input only once. You need to get the input every single time the loop iterates. The best way of doing this is to add `grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))` inside the `while` loop. This way when you enter into the loop the first time, it checks if the first number you input is a positive, and then every time it iterates, it checks again if your new input is a positive. If it is not, then it will just exit out of the `while` loop and not iterate again. Also, `else` statements are normally only used for `if` and `try` statements so you do not need it here. Instead just un-indent the lines.

```
grades = []

print('When done inputting grades input any negative number.')
grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))

while (grade >= 0):
    grades.append(grade)
    grade = int(input('Input grades here: '))

avg_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
print('Average grade: ' , avg_grade)
print('Lowest grade: ' , min(grades))
print('Highest grade: ', max(grades))
```